# What does it mean to "chirp" a gear?

Tags: noise, clutch, manual-transmission, flywheel

In [this clutch / flywheel replacement guide](https://www.thecarpassionchannel.com/clutch-install), during the test drive, the driver says "I just chirped second gear! This car has never chirped second gear.".

I do hear the quick "chirp" sound as he shifts (into? out of?) second gear, but I don't understand what causes it or why the driver is excited about it. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chirp is in reference to the noise the drive tire makes when it slips a little bit when engaging the clutch from one gear to another.

Comment: I would only add, the noise is usually only heard during high acceleration activities.

Comment: Depends on the horsepower and torque of the engine.